# Repositioning of xlabels

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

using my plot code in matlab, why still I have problem positioning the `xlabel` ? I need to bring down the XLabel.Y position by -0.03 as you could see in the image.

```
figure;
h2=bar([mean(o2_ExecNorm(:,:,8)-1,2) mean(o3_ExecNorm(:,:,5)-1,2)]);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',unique([bench.application]), 'XTick',1:numel(unique([bench.application])))
hold on
axis([0 25 -0.3 2.5])
set(gca,'FontName','AvantGarde')
xticklabel_rotate([],35,[]) 
set(findobj(gca,'Type','text'),'FontSize',14, 'FontWeight','Bold','FontName','courier');
set(gcf, 'color', [1 1 1])
ylabel({'Performance improvement w.r.t -O3 and -O2'},'FontSize',24,'FontWeight','bold');
legend({'w.r.t -O2','w.r.t -O3'})
```

Apparently this part does not work:

```
vec_pos = get(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Position');
set(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Position', vec_pos + [0 -0.03 0]);
set(gca,'YTickLabel', 1:.5:3)
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: You could try adding some spaces to the end of the tick label strings.

Comment: @A.Donda, yes but I would like to use the Y Position of XLabel, they are a lot of XlabelTicks

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? is `xticklabel_rotate` from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate)? I just tried it with demo data and it looks good (R2015a).

Comment: it is `8.4.0.150421 (R2014b)` on Mac OSx

Comment: You should mention that `xticklabel_rotate` is from the file exchange. Sorry, no idea. But adding spaces isn't that hard; just loop over your labels programmatically.

Comment: thanks for the answer @A.Donda, yes it is possible, I just wanna know why I can't do that via the scripts, cuz in the plot editor mode I can manually re-position them changing the Y value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is not to use `xticklabel_rotate`. It became obsolete with **Matlab R2014b** and the introduction of the new graphics engine.

Instead do the following:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 35;
```

Have some further insight here: [**MATLAB R2014b Graphics – Part 1: Features of the New Graphics System**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/10/03/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-1-features-of-the-new-graphics-system/#b481d70c-0e8e-4c8c-ae37-4ea3ceca9fcc)

Probably the new graphics engine also causes `xticklabel_rotate` not to work properly anymore.